# outlook macro - run on the content as I type out the email

Tags: vba, outlook

I need to run a macro on the content of an email as I am typing out the email, in MSOutlook 2010.

I am planning to run this macro on the content of the email - which is basically a minutes of meeting. If at the end of a line, there is a @ sign I want to that particular line to be formatted differently, as it is a TODO for one of the attendees.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, it is possible to develop a macro which replace some text in the body. The Outlook object model provides three different ways for working with item bodies:

1. Body - a plain text.
2. HTMLBody - an HTML markup.
3. The Word Editor. Outlook uses Word as an email editor, so you can use it to format the email message. The [WordEditor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868196(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Inspector class returns an instance of the Document class which represents the message body.

You can read more about all these ways in the [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx) in MSDN.

But the Outlook object model doesn't provide any event for that. You may try to handle the following events of Outlook items:

- [BeforeAutoSave](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868926.aspx) - is fired before the item is automatically saved by Outlook.
- [PropertyChange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865835(v=office.15).aspx) - is fired when an explicit built-in property (for example, Subject) of an instance of the parent object is changed.